# How to insert data by using linq to sql concept

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to insert the data via linq to sql concept. i wrote down the code like this. here customers is the table name in which i want to insert the data. How to achieve it?
following code is not working. How to insert the data via this concept.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim context As New linq_to_sql_classesDataContext
        Dim custid As New Customer
        custid.CustomerID = Trim(txt_custid.Text)
        custid.CompanyName = Trim(txt_companyname.Text)
        custid.ContactName = Trim(txt_contactname.Text)
        custid.ContactTitle = Trim(txt_contacttitle.Text)
        custid.Address = Trim(txt_address.Text)
        custid.City = Trim(txt_city.Text)
        custid.Region = Trim(txt_region.Text)
        custid.PostalCode = Trim(txt_postalcode.Text)
        custid.Country = Trim(txt_country.Text)
        custid.Phone = Trim(txt_phone.Text)
        custid.Fax = Trim(txt_fax.Text)

        context.Customers.Attach(custid)
        context.SubmitChanges()
    End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `InsertOnSubmit` method:

```
context.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(custid)
context.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: the problem not solved..! when clicking the submit button then no action is going to perform

Comment: @Mihir: You can do the following to diagnose the problem. 1. Hook a `TextWriter` onto the `DataContext.Log` (http://bit.ly/hiYVjm) (i.e. `context.Log = System.Console.Out`) to see if and which SQL commands are executed. 2. Use the `DataContext.GetChangeSet()` (http://bit.ly/nUrRE) method to see which methods will be inserted, updated and deleted (i.e. `Response.Write(context.GetChangeSet().Inserts.First().GetType().Name)`).

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
     context.Customers.Add(custid)
```

Comment: @Daniel.. when i use add() then it is showing add is not a member of system.Data.linq.table..

Answer (score 0):

Check This Link To Learn LINQ To SQL Insertion:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/03/11/inserting-data-to-database-using-linq-to-sql.aspx

```
private void SaveCustomerInfo()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext())

    {

        //Create a new instance of the Customer object

        Customer cust = new Customer();

        //Add new values to each fields

        cust.CustomerID = TextBoxID.Text;

        cust.CompanyName = TextBoxCompanyName.Text;

        cust.ContactName = TextBoxContactName.Text;

        cust.ContactTitle = TextBoxContactTitle.Text;

        cust.Address = TextBoxAddress.Text;

        cust.City = TextBoxCity.Text;

        cust.Region = TextBoxRegion.Text;

        cust.PostalCode = TextBoxPostalCode.Text;

        cust.Country = TextBoxCountry.Text;



        //Insert the new Customer object

        context.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(cust);

        //Sumbit changes to the database

        context.SubmitChanges();



        //Display Message for successful operation

        LiteralMessage.Text = "<p style='color:Green;'>Information Successfully saved!</p>";

    }

}
```